# How to access the msal graph api without getting 401 error

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, msal.js

I have been using msal to log users into the app using the `acquireTokenSilent` call and that works perfectly fine. I am able to get the response token which contains things like the `accessToken` and `idToken` among other things. but when trying to use the graph api to get the account photo by using any of these tokens in the the bearer header I get a 401 error. I am calling it correctly because by using the token shown here [in the graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) it works fine.

Essentially my question is, how do I get this access token to call the graph api.

I am trying to do this in a web app using JavaScript.

```
    axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + this.username + "/photos/48x48/$value", {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization:
                            "Bearer " +
                            "insertTokenHere"
                    },
                    responseType: "blob"
                })

                .then(response => {
```

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample, specifically including the scopes you are requesting and the api calls to graph. And any correlation ids for requests to aad and graph.

Comment: I am not setting a scope could that be my issue? also updated with the way I am calling the graph api. I am looking for how to get the right token to replace "insertTokenHere" if a copy the value from the graph explorer it works but I cant do that on a deployed app

Comment: make sure permissions are set correctly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to make it work -

1. Based on authorization protocol, obtain bearer tokens to access endpoints. Refer documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) if you are using authorization code flow.
2. Scope parameter is required which is nothing but a space-separated list of [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent) that you want the user to consent to. Make sure you understand the necessary permissions for each of the API endpoint. Necessary permissions for each API endpoint are documented in ms docs. Refer for an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Also, ensure admin has consented wherever needed.

Thanks.